# java.util.logging How to override the handler log level for specific packages?

Tags: java, logging

In `java.util.logging` log configuration, I want to override the console log level specifically for some packages, how can I do that?

For example, I tried the configuration

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level= INFO

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

com.mypackage.MyClass.level= ALL
```

The `MyClass` log level being set to `ALL`, but it do not seem to log anything less than info on the console.

Comment: Can we see the line you are using to create the logger in your class?

Comment: There you go, private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());

Answer (score 1):

I think , you should give the log level at package level, not at the class level.

Try `com.mypackage.level= ALL` **instead of** `com.mypackage.MyClass.level= ALL`.

Also you can edit these settings by login to WAS admin console, under logs and traces.